# Multiplying complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm doing some AC circuits problems and it involves complex numbers.

In the textbook, it was given that the multiplication of complex numbers, in polar form is:

$$z_1 \cdot z_2 = r_1 r_2 \angle (\phi_1 + \phi_2)$$

and using $R \angle (\phi) = R e^{i(\phi)}$.

Multiplying $$(5.01 e^{i(-11.3)}) \cdot(100 e^{i60}),$$ I get $$501e^{i48.7}$$ as an answer. ($501 \angle(48.7)$)

However, using Wolfram Alpha, the answer shows as $501e^{i(-89.69)}$. ($501\angle(-89.69)$).

Please help me clear things up. Thank you.

edit: angles are in degrees.

Comment: could you please retype the question defining what your variables mean?

Comment: Sorry. Complex number z. Radius r. Angle phi. Someone kindly edited my post. It looks clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+5.01*e%5E%28i*%28-11.3%29%29*%28100*e%5E%28i*60%29%29) gives a slightly different answer than you wrote here: namely, it gives the angle in degrees ($\theta = -89.6955°$) whereas you give your angle in radians ($48.7$).

$e^{i\theta}$ is periodic, with period $2\pi$. If you subtract $16\pi$ from your angle you get $-1.565482$ radians: converting that to degrees by multiplying by $\frac {180°}{\pi}$ you get Wolfram's $-89.6955°$.

So your answers agree, you just use different units, and Wolfram used the reduced reference angle.

Comment: Thank you! So it's the same, but where did subtracting 16pi come from?
Also, how did my answer become in radians, I'm unclear about that.

Comment: @VeeJeyVee $e^{i\theta}$ uses an angle $\theta$ in radians. (That's why $e^{i\pi}$ is $-1$.) Usually $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, so $-1.57$ is preferable to $48.7$.

Comment: @VeeJeyVee: You did not state a unit for the angles in your question, and the usual math convention is to assume that any angle without a stated unit is in radians. If you mean degrees, add the symbol to your question. (What I don't understand is why Wolfram Alpha gave its answer in degrees.) Anyway, $e^{2k\pi i}=1$ so adding or subtracting any multiple of $2\pi$ radians to/from the angle does not change the complex number. Another math convention is to give the angle so $-\pi<\theta \le \pi$, so Wolfram used a multiple of $2\pi$ to get the angle in that range.

Comment: The values I used were in degrees. The hand computed and wolfram computed are both in degrees. I was wondering how MY hand computation became radians.

$$z = x+ iy = R \angle (\phi) = Re^{i\phi}$$

By this, shouldn't it stay consistent? --- Or is it by using $$z_1 \cdot z_2 = r_1 r_2 \angle (\phi_1 + \phi_2)$$, it becomes radians? Sorry for my confusion and lack of knowledge.

Comment: @VeeJeyVee: The formula works for radians or degrees. But when interpreted as radians, your numbers give an answer outside the usual range $-\pi<\theta \le 2\pi$ or $-180°<\theta \le 180°$, So Wolfram Alpha reduce the angle to be in those limits. In other words, you were not confused by the units, you were confused by the limits on the angle--which was made apparent by the units.

Comment: So they are the same answer, correct? I'm not sure what it means by "reduce the angle to be in those limits". Isn't 48.7° within the range of −180°<θ≤180°?

Comment: @VeeJeyVee: Yes, but $48.7$ *radians* is not in that range. Again, Wolfram interpreted your angles as in radians. My quote should have been "reduced the angle," such as changing $375°$ to $15°$ to get the angle between $0°$ and $360°$.